# get the largest id in json with status : 0

Tags: php, json

```
<?php
$data='[
  {
    "status": 1,
    "id": 101
  },
  {
    "status": 0,
    "id": 102
  },
  {
    "status": 0,
    "id": 103
  }
]';

$obj=json_decode($data);
        $max = 0;
        for($i = 0; $i < count($obj); $i++)
        {
            if($obj[$i]->{"id"} > $max)
                $max = $obj[$i]->{"id"};
        }
        echo $max;
?>
```

I have to get the largest id in the json provided where status is 0.

My code loops through whole JSON but it should only loop through where status is 0 and give largest id and if no status 0 is found in JSON it should echo "no status 0". can someone please help.

Comment: Have you tried `if($obj[$i]->status != 0) continue`?

Comment: You can use `usort` with your own callback, and then maybe `array_filter` everything with status!=0, and then get the first (or last, depending on sorting order) entry of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
if($obj[$i]["status"] == 0)
  // do your work here
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if($obj[$i]->{"status"} == 0 && $obj[$i]->{"id"} > $max)
```

instead

```
if($obj[$i]->{"id"} > $max)
```